# Looping through Word documents to extract table data and place into Excel

Tags: excel, loops, ms-word, vba

I currently need to extract data from a Word table and place it into Excel.  I am able to do this on a file by file basis. I need to be able to loop through all the word documents in a file path.

More specifically,  I need to be able to open up a word file read the info from the tables on that word file import the information needed below, close that word file and then repeat for all word files (doc, or docx) in a specified folder.

Currently my code is this:

```
Sub ImportWordTable()

Dim eRow As Long
Dim ele As Object
Dim mainBook As Workbook
Set mainBook = ActiveWorkbook
mainBook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A:BB").Clear

Set sht = Sheets("sheet1")
Application.Goto (ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1"))


    Dim wordDoc As Object
    Dim wdFileName As Variant
    Dim noTble As Integer
    Dim rowNb As Long
    Dim colNb As Integer
    Sheet1.Range("A1").Select
         Dim x As Long, y As Long
    x = 1: y = 1
    Dim sPath As String
    Dim sFil As String
    Dim owb As Workbook
    Dim twb As Workbook

wdFileName = Application.GetOpenFilename("Word files (*.docx),*.docx", , _
    "Browse for file containing table to be imported")

 If wdFileName = False Then Exit Sub
 Set wordDoc = GetObject(wdFileName)
    With wordDoc
        noTble = wordDoc.tables.Count
        If noTble = 0 Then
           MsgBox "No Tables in this document", vbExclamation, "No Tables to Import"
            Exit Sub
        End If

          For k = 1 To noTble
            With .tables(k)
                For rowNb = 1 To .Rows.Count
                    For colNb = 1 To .Columns.Count
                        Cells(x, y) = WorksheetFunction.Clean(.cell(rowNb, colNb).Range.Text)
                        y = 0
                    Next colNb
                    y = 1

                Next rowNb
            End With
            x = x + 1
        Next
     Range("A1").Select
    ActiveCell.Replace What:="Cotnact InformationName", Replacement:="", _
        LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:= _
        False, ReplaceFormat:=False
    ActiveCell.Replace What:="Email", Replacement:="", _
        LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:= _
        False, ReplaceFormat:=False
    ActiveCell.Replace What:="Contact InformationName", Replacement:="", _
        LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:= _
        False, ReplaceFormat:=False
    ActiveCell.Replace What:="Address", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False
   ActiveCell.Replace What:="Location", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False
Range("A1").Select
    ActiveCell.Replace What:="Phone", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False
   ActiveCell.Replace What:="Cell", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False
   ActiveCell.Replace What:="Fax", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False
   ActiveCell.Replace What:="Re:", Replacement:=":", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False
   Range("A3").Select
    ActiveCell.Replace What:="Preferred Position and RoutePreferred Position(s)" _
        , Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:= _
        False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
   ActiveCell.Replace What:="preferred Route(s)", Replacement:="", LookAt:= _
        xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False
    Range("A4").Select
    ActiveCell.Replace What:="Experience ad skillsDriving experience", _
        Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:= _
        False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
    ActiveCell.Replace What:="Experience and skillsDriving experience", _
        Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:= _
        False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
    ActiveCell.Replace What:="trucks driven", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart _
        , SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False
     ActiveCell.Replace What:="other skills/experience", Replacement:="", _
        LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:= _
        False, ReplaceFormat:=False
     ActiveCell.Replace What:="licensingdriver License", Replacement:="", _
        LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:= _
        False, ReplaceFormat:=False
    Range("A5").Select
    ActiveCell.Replace What:="licensingdriver License", Replacement:="", _
        LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:= _
        False, ReplaceFormat:=False
     ActiveCell.Replace What:="license number", Replacement:="", LookAt:= _
        xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False
      ActiveCell.Replace What:="state/prov.", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False

    ActiveCell.Replace What:="hazmat", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False

    Range("A6").Select
    ActiveCell.Replace What:="driving recordlicense ever suspended?", _
        Replacement:=":", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:= _
        False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False

    ActiveCell.Replace What:="DUI's", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False
    ActiveCell.Replace What:="DUis", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False

    ActiveCell.Replace What:="moving violations in last 3 years", Replacement:= _
        "", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, _
        SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False

    ActiveCell.Replace What:="preventable accidents in last 3 years", _
        Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:= _
        False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False

    ActiveCell.Replace What:="employment status", Replacement:="", LookAt:= _
        xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False
    Range("A7").Select
    ActiveCell.Replace What:="employment status", Replacement:="", LookAt:= _
        xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False

    Range("A8").Select
    ActiveCell.Replace What:="job history", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False

    Range("A2").Select
    ActiveCell.Replace What:="profile summary", Replacement:="", LookAt:= _
        xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False

    Range("A9").Select
    ActiveCell.Replace What:="Resume", Replacement:="", LookAt:= _
        xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False
    Range("A1:A6").Select
    Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("A1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
        TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=False, _
        Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=True, OtherChar _
        :=":", FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 2), Array(2, 1), Array(3, 1), Array(4, 1), Array(5, _
        1), Array(6, 1), Array(7, 1), Array(8, 1), Array(9, 1)), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
    Range("B9").Select


Application.Goto (ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1").Range("B1:I1"))
Selection.Copy
Application.Goto (ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("sheet3").Range("A2"))
     Dim BlankRow As Long
 BlankRow = Range("A65000").End(xlUp).Row + 1
Cells(BlankRow, 1).Select
 ActiveSheet.Paste
 Application.Goto (ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1").Range("A2"))
Selection.Copy
Application.Goto (ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("sheet3").Range("A2"))
BlankRow = Range("A65000").End(xlUp).Cells(1, 9).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Application.Goto (ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1").Range("B3:C3"))
Selection.Copy
Application.Goto (ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("sheet3").Range("A2"))
BlankRow = Range("A65000").End(xlUp).Cells(1, 10).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Application.Goto (ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1").Range("B4:D4"))
Selection.Copy
Application.Goto (ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("sheet3").Range("A2"))
BlankRow = Range("A65000").End(xlUp).Cells(1, 12).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Application.Goto (ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1").Range("B5:F5"))
Selection.Copy
Application.Goto (ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("sheet3").Range("A2"))
BlankRow = Range("A65000").End(xlUp).Cells(1, 15).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Application.Goto (ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1").Range("B6:E6"))
Selection.Copy
Application.Goto (ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("sheet3").Range("A2"))
BlankRow = Range("A65000").End(xlUp).Cells(1, 20).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Application.Goto (ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1").Range("A7"))
Selection.Copy
Application.Goto (ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("sheet3").Range("A2"))
BlankRow = Range("A65000").End(xlUp).Cells(1, 24).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Application.Goto (ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1").Range("A8"))
Selection.Copy
Application.Goto (ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("sheet3").Range("A2"))
BlankRow = Range("A65000").End(xlUp).Cells(1, 25).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Application.Goto (ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1").Range("A9"))
Selection.Copy
Application.Goto (ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("sheet3").Range("A2"))
BlankRow = Range("A65000").End(xlUp).Cells(1, 26).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste

    End With
    Set wordDoc = Nothing


End Sub
```

Comment: You can use `Dir()` to loop through all files in a folder.  If you adapt your existing code to add a string parameter to pass in a file path, you can just call that from a separate sub where you use Dir() to loop through the files.

Comment: Can you be more specific about your problem? When you run your code what's not working, what errors do you get, etc.?